# How do I view errors my Flask App is returning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I've started to make an app using Python 3 with the Flask framework. I mostly followed this [tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/creating-first-flask-web-app/). I'm currently using a free-tier AWS Ubuntu-16.04 server to host the app on while trying to develop it.

How am I meant to see the errors that my Flask App is returning?  - as most of the time I receive a 500 Internal Server Error in my browser. Also is there an easier setup I should be using to develop and debug the app.

Thanks

Edit 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from flask import Flask, render_template, request


app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True


@app.route('/table')
def current_return():
    data = ['one', 'two', 'three']
    return render_template("current.html",data = data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should enable debugging for your app.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
```

That will output the traceback on the error pages, instead of just a generic 'Server error' page.

Comment: I had this at the top of my __init__.py but I still recieve '500 Internal Server Errors'. I added my init.py to the main post

Comment: Then that means Apache is handling errors, not Flask. You must configure apache accordingly.

Comment: Ah, Thanks. I found where the errors were being logged to. How would I go about showing them in a browser instead?